# How to position a CSS box below a group of divs with floating divs?

Tags: css

I have working layout with two `div`s (orange and blue) floating left and right of fixed size of a middle `div` (green) which is supposed to expand to the bottom.

Now, I'd like to add a footer (red) which is displayed below the highest of the above `div`s, but I only get it do display below the middle `div` as shown below.

I tried `overflow: auto`, but it has no effect.

```html
<div style="float: left;width: 100px;border-style: solid;border-color: orange;">
left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating 
</div>
<div style="float: right;border-style: solid;border-color: blue;">
right floating right floating right<br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating 
</div>
<div style="layout:block;border-style: solid;border-color: green;">
middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle 
</div>
<div style="display:block;border-style: solid;border-color: red;">
footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to the red div.

```
<div style="float: left;width: 100px;border-style: solid;border-color: orange;">
left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating left floating 
</div>
<div style="float: right;border-style: solid;border-color: blue;">
right floating right floating right<br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating right floating right <br/>
floating 
</div>
<div style="layout:block;border-style: solid;border-color: green;">
middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle 
</div>
<div style="display:block;border-style: solid;border-color: red;clear: both">
footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6c4713ym/